# how to call object A's method from object B which itself is a property of the A's object?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

I have a login form dialog box which is displayed in the beginning step and user must login to continue to the application. the problem is that I don't know how the application should know when the login process is completed and continue. I think I should register a `WindowListener` and implement the `windowClosing` event. and inside it I should call a method from my application to continue the process. But I don't know how this solution is correct. because I implemented the login form as a class which extends `JDialog` and application instantiated it as a local variable. thus I think it is not correct to call the application's methods from inside the `Login` class. I'm not sure. It's just a feeling. 
What do you suggest?

```
public class Application {
    private Login login = null;
    public Application() {
       login = new Login();   
    }

    public continue() {
        //...
    }
}

public class Login extends JDialog {
    public Login() {
       //...
    }

    public void processLogin() {
    }

    private class WindowEventHandler implements WindowListener {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            if(#LoginProcessSuccessful?) {
                // call application's continue method
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use and [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) (AKA a listener).

Basically, the `Login` would provide some kind registration process that would allow interested parties to register themselves with the instance of the class.

When the required event occurs, the `Login` would notify each of these parties that the event has occurred...

The basic premises is to limit the amount of information you are expose between classes.  The `Login` shouldn't care about anything else other then telling the listener that some event has occured.  It also means that you are not tightly coupling your code together, giving your greater flexibility.

```
public interface LoginListener {
    public void loginSucceeded(); // You want to return some information about the caller...
    public void loginFailed();
}

public class Application implements LoginListener {
    private Login login = null;
    public Application() {
        login = new Login(this);   
    }    
    public void loginSucceeded() {
        // Yea for me
    }
    public void loginFailed() {
        // Sucks for you
    }
}

public class Login extends JDialog {
    private LoginListener listener;
    public Login(LoginListener listener) {
       //...
    }

    public void processLogin() {
        if (loginSuccessful()) {
            listener.loginSucceeded();
        } else {
            listener.loginFailed();
        }
    }

}
```

Note: This example uses a single listener, there's no reason why you should limit it in this way and you could provide a mechanism for registering multiple callbacks

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Application {
    private Login login = null;
    public Application() {
       login = new Login(this);   
    }

    public continue() {
        //...
    }
}

public class Login extends JDialog {
   Application app;
    public Login(Application app) {
      this.app=app;
    }

    public void processLogin() {
    }

    private class WindowEventHandler implements WindowListener {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            if(#LoginProcessSuccessful?) {
                this.app.continue()
            }
        }
    }
}
```